# How to copy columns when there are blanks in the data?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I've been trying to copy several columns from another file (from several sheets).

I created a kind of matrix where the user can configure the name and column position to copy. I realized when there is a blank in a column my code is copying from, it skips the information next to the blank cell and moves on to the next sheet.

Another option I was thinking of is to fill all the blanks with a module as function and call it to my main program but I don't know how:

```vb
'GLOBAL VARIABLES
'
'Variable used to pick a file in the beginning ("Activo Fijo" File)
Dim file_in As String
'Variable to name the Workbook where are generated the macro file
Dim Entrance As Workbook
'Variable to calculate the accumulated range of the "Activo Fijo" (columns)
Dim x, a As Long
'Variables to measure the rows and columns on the "Configuration" sheet (located on the Macro Workbook)
Dim y, w As Integer
'Variable to measure the copy range from "Activo Fijo"
Dim seg1 As String
'Variable to copy info
Dim copyinfo As String
'Variable to locate the "Activo Fijo" file sheets on the matrix
Dim pestana As String
'Variable to measure the matrix range
Dim seg2 As RANGE
'Variable to change the matrix range
Dim rangesize As String
'Variable to create the new Workbook where is pasted the info
Dim wc As Workbook

'CLEAR THE ALREADY CONSOLIDATED DATA
'
'Subroutine to erased the old data and generate the new ones
Sub clean()

Me.Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents

End Sub

'CONSOLIDATING ALL SOURCES AND NECESSARY SHEETS FROM "ACTIVO FIJO" FILE
'
'Subroutine to take all necessary information from the input file to create PANDA file
Sub ActivoFijo()
'sentences to avoid unnecessary Pop-Ups
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Instruction to pick a file ("Activo Fijo" File)
file_in = Module1.pick_file("Selecionar Activo Fijo")

If (file_in = "") Then
'Exit if the file is not found
    Exit Sub
End If
'Open if the file is found
Set Entrance = Workbooks.Open(file_in)

clean
'Giving value 1 to skip headers
a = 1
'Measuring until the last row on the "Configuration" sheet

y = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

'Measuring until the last column on the "Configuration" sheet

w = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

'LOOP TO GENERATE CONSOLIDATED INFO
'
'READING THE DATA ON THE MATRIX LOCATED ON THE "CONFIGURATION" SHEET
'

Do While y <> 1

'Pop-Up that shows up if exist and column name error

    pestana = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(y, 1).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(Entrance.Sheets(pestana).Select) Then
    Msgbox ("El nombre de alguna pestaña esta mal escrito. Reviselo y vuelva a ejecutar")

    Else
        End If
    Entrance.Sheets(pestana).Select
    rangesize = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(y, 2).Value
    Set seg2 = RANGE(rangesize, RANGE(rangesize).End(xlDown))
    x = seg2.Count
    For Z = 2 To w


'READING THE DATA ON THE "ACTIVO FIJO" FILE AFTER HAVE BEEN SEARCHED ON THE MATRIX
'
            If a = 1 Then
                Me.Sheets(2).Cells(1, Z - 1).Value = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(1, Z).Value
                copyinfo = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(y, Z)
                If Z = w Then

'Loop to "TRAMOS FO" Sheet to add to its columns the "x"item (item used on the process)

                    If copyinfo <> "" Then
                        For tfo = 1 To x
                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + tfo, Z - 1).Value = copyinfo
                        Next tfo
                    End If
                Else

'If the column is not needed or is not mapping on the matrix, go to next column

                    If copyinfo = "" Then
                        GoTo moveforeward
                    Else
                        If IsNumeric(Mid(copyinfo, 2, 1)) Then

'Copying info if occurs the first case

                            seg1 = copyinfo & ":" & Left(copyinfo, 1) & seg2.item(x).Row
                            RANGE(seg1).copy

'Pasting info if occurs the first case

                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + 1, Z - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        Else

'Copying info if occurs the second case

                            seg1 = copyinfo & ":" & Left(copyinfo, 2) & seg2.item(x).Row
                            RANGE(seg1).copy

'Pasting info if occurs the second case

                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + 1, Z - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                copyinfo = Me.Sheets(3).Cells(y, Z)
                If Z = w Then

'Loop to "TRAMOS FO" Sheet to add to its columns the "x"item (item used on the process)

                    If copyinfo <> "" Then
                        For tfo = 1 To x
                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + 1 + tfo, Z - 1).Value = copyinfo
                        Next tfo
                    End If
                Else

'If the column is not needed or is not mapping on the matrix, go to next column

                    If copyinfo = "" Then
                        GoTo moveforeward
                    Else

'If the column is out of range, change it to the mid item and read from there to do not copy unnecessary info

                        If IsNumeric(Mid(copyinfo, 2, 1)) Then
                            seg1 = copyinfo & ":" & Left(copyinfo, 1) & seg2.item(x).Row
                            RANGE(seg1).copy
                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + 1, Z - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        Else

'If the column is not out of range, read it normal

                            seg1 = copyinfo & ":" & Left(copyinfo, 2) & seg2.item(x).Row
                            RANGE(seg1).copy
                            Me.Sheets(2).Cells(a + 1, Z - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If


moveforeward:
    Next Z

'formulas to keep increasing and decreasing ranges

    y = y - 1
    a = a + x

Loop
        SaveFile
        Entrance.Close
End Sub

'SAVING NEW "ACTIVO FIJO" FILE ALREADY CONSOLIDATED
'
'Subroutine to copy consolidated "Activo fijo" File sheet on a new Workbook
Sub SaveFile()
'Variable to create a new workbook
Set wc = Workbooks.Add
'Using "Me" Variable to copy sheet 2 from the macro file
'Using destination property to paste sheet 2 from the macro file on the already created new Workbook ("wc" variable)
Me.Sheets(2).UsedRange.copy Destination:=wc.Sheets(1).RANGE("A1")
'Using TempFile properties to saving the new Workbook as a new file with XSLX extention, and name it as "AF" (Do Not Change name). It will be used on the nex processes
    TempFilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    TempFileName = "AF" & "_" & Format(Now, "mm-yy")
    With wc
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
'Pop-Up that shows up the path and the save file direction
    End With
    Msgbox "A generado un nuevo archivo en " & TempFilePath
'Ending routine
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple things - try to avoid using so many comments. Reserve comments for when you REALLY need to convey something to the reader. Instead of using `y`, use something like `lastrow` instead - that'll give more readability than any comment would. Also, instead of using `.End(xlDown).Row` and `.End(xlToRight).Column`, you should use `xlUp` and `xlToLeft` instead - this will allow you to capture all the rows, even if there's a blank in column A.